# Obtain in/out streams to file via process (shell)

Tags: android, shell, inputstream, outputstream

My application (DataSync) has to read and write files that can only be accessed by root, so I'm limited to using the shell to manipulate these files. I currently copy a file I'd like to access to a cache directory, after which I can create an input or outputstream to the cached file from my Java code. Writing a file happens the same way (but the other way around).

Since caching this file is relatively time consuming I'd like to directly read or write from/to these files without the need of a cache directory. I'm basically trying to use the process input and outputstreams to read or write to a file, like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();
InputStream in   = p.getInputStream();

// Write open file command to outputstream

// Read file contents from inputStream

out.close();
in.close();
```

I'd need to open a file from the process, and direct it to stdout so my Java application can read the said file (and something similar for writing). However, I'm not very familiar with Linux so I have no clue as to where to get started. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Quint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just answer my own question. Here's how I'm doing it at the moment:

```
public static InputStream getInputStream(File file) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        return new FileInputStream(file);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream outputS = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());

        outputS.writeBytes("cat \"" + file.getPath() + "\"\n");

        outputS.writeBytes("exit\n");
        outputS.flush();
        outputS.close();

        return p.getInputStream();
    }
}
```

And for the OutputStream:

```
public static OutputStream getOutputStream(File file) throws IOException
{
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream outputS = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());

    outputS.writeBytes("mkdir -p \"" + file.getParent() + "\"\n");
    outputS.writeBytes("cat - > \"" + file.getPath() + "\"\n");

    return (OutputStream) outputS;
}
```